# How to do HABTM management with auto completion in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, associations

I am looking for a good solution for a probably typical problem of managing models with HABTM association in Rails.

Let's assume that we have two models -- products and categories:

```
Products
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
Categories
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
Categorization
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
```

Pat Shaughnessy is developing [modified auto_complete plugin](http://www.github.com/patshaughnessy/auto_complete) which can allow to manage one-to-many (and many-to-many) association:

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9141/samplef.th.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/i/samplef.png/) [alt text http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/4075/sampleautocomplete.th.png](http://img406.imageshack.us/i/sampleautocomplete.png/)

For someone that would be enough, but I don't really like so many text fields. I guess it is possible to combine the [Ryan Bates' screencasts](http://railscasts.com/) used by Pat in a slightly different way, namely, **using one text field** with autocomplete:

[alt text http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9576/betterautocomplete.th.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/i/betterautocomplete.png/)

Also it would be better **to remove** from the list of suggested tasks (one-to-many), or products|categories (many-to-many) those which have been **already added**.

In the case of products-categories relationship, such auto completion would be used both in the form for product, and in the form for category.

I hope that there is an existing plugin for that. I am not very experienced in Ruby, and don't really know how to implement such logic by myself.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a good idea and shouldn't be too difficult to do though it will require knowledge of JavaScript. It's actually more of a JavaScript issue than a Rails one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is nicely solved using  [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin, as shown by Ryan Bates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get the tokens shown in a edit form for with nested_attributes on the 3rd level? on creating it works excellent but when loading the edit form i can't find a way to show the saved tokens for that relation in the nested form. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also need a similar. but so far I found two plugins for jQuery.

1. The "Tagger"
   chrisiufer.com/tagger, but without autocomplete function.
2. And "Advanced Uses of Auto Complete"
   http://education.llnl.gov/jquery/adv_auto.lasso

It would be cool if someone could remake it for the Ruby on Rails. :) If you have a ready solution, please put the code!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the model_auto_completer will help.

http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/model_auto_completer